# Refreshing map using asyncTask error

Tags: android, google-maps, android-asynctask, handle

I'm trying to refresh a map with some coordinates that i get from a webserver. This is my AsyncTask:

```
public class GetUsersAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{

    HttpResponse response = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    AndroidHttpClient httpclient;
    String responseString = null;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

        try{
            Log.i("entrabackground",""+(++ae));
        httpclient = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android");
        Log.i("!!","upa upa");
        HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(mUrl+eventid);
        Log.i("!!","taaa beemmm");
        request.addHeader("Accept","application/json");
        Log.i("!!","oh pahhh");

    response = httpclient.execute(request);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
            Log.i("erro1","Erro");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        Log.i("erro2","Erro");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
        httpclient.close();

    try {
        if( String.valueOf(response.getEntity()) == "null")
        {
            responseString= "null";
            Log.i("null", responseString.toString());
        }
        else
        {
            is = response.getEntity().getContent();
            responseString = convertStreamToString(is);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.i("saibackgroud",""+(++ao));

    return responseString;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String responseString) {
    //super.onPostExecute(responseString);
    //Do anything with response..
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),                 responseString,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Log.i("entrapost",""+(++ai));
    try 
    {
        json = new JSONObject(responseString.trim());
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), json.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }                   
    catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try{
        Log.i("faz isto",""+(++au));
        users_locations = json.getJSONArray("user");
        userdraw.removeOverlay(item);
        mapView.invalidate();


    user_name=users_locations.getJSONObject(0).getString("name");
    user_lat=users_locations.getJSONObject(0).getDouble("latitude");
    user_lng=users_locations.getJSONObject(0).getDouble("longitude");
    userpoint = new GeoPoint((int) (user_lat * 1E6), (int) (user_lng * 1E6));
    item = new OverlayItem(userpoint,null,null);
    //Get the new Drawable
    //Set its bounds
    usermarker.setBounds(-usermarker.getIntrinsicWidth()/2,-   usermarker.getIntrinsicHeight(),usermarker.getIntrinsicWidth()/2,0);
    //Set the new marker
    item.setMarker(usermarker);
    userdraw.addOverlay(item);      
    mc.animateTo(userpoint);
    mapView.invalidate();
    Log.i("userslocations",user_name+" "+user_lat+" "+user_lng);

    }catch (JSONException e) {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection Lost", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

This asyncTask is called from a handler:

```
handler = new Handler();
      runnable = new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
          Log.i("url",mUrl+eventid);
          /* do what you need to do */
          //call asynctask
          GetUsersAsyncTask getusers = new GetUsersAsyncTask();
          getusers.execute(mUrl+eventid).toString();

          /* and here comes the "trick" */
          //10 seconds delay
          handler.postDelayed(this, 30000);
       }
    };
    runnable.run();
```

Some point on PostExecution task an error occurs and i don't know why. It seems that is on `json = new JSONObject(responseString.trim());`

This is my LogCat:

> 01-16 00:44:37.005: E/AndroidRuntime(8625): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
>   01-16 00:44:37.105: E/AndroidRuntime(8625): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   01-16 00:44:37.105: E/AndroidRuntime(8625):     at com.example.su2.EventMap$GetUsersAsyncTask.onPostExecute(EventMap.java:273)
>   01-16 00:44:37.105: E/AndroidRuntime(8625):     at com.example.su2.EventMap$GetUsersAsyncTask.onPostExecute(EventMap.java:1)
>   01-16 00:44:37.105: E/AndroidRuntime(8625):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
>   01-16 00:44:37.105: E/AndroidRuntime(8625):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
>   01-16 00:44:37.105: E/AndroidRuntime(8625):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
>   01-16 00:44:37.105: E/AndroidRuntime(8625):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   01-16 00:44:37.105: E/AndroidRuntime(8625):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   01-16 00:44:37.105: E/AndroidRuntime(8625):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4370)
>   01-16 00:44:37.105: E/AndroidRuntime(8625):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   01-16 00:44:37.105: E/AndroidRuntime(8625):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   01-16 00:44:37.105: E/AndroidRuntime(8625):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   01-16 00:44:37.105: E/AndroidRuntime(8625):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>   01-16 00:44:37.105: E/AndroidRuntime(8625):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   01-16 00:44:37.285: E/SemcCheckin(8625): Get crash dump level : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/semc-checkin/crashdump

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure **responseString** is not null.

If it is *null* then calling **responseString.trim()** will result in *java.lang.NullPointerException* like the above stack trace shows.

Comment: Yes, responseString is not null. Now i'm getting a different error, something in doInBackgroud isn't working properly. These are the logcat messages:

Comment: 01-16 15:27:56.783: E/AndroidRuntime(12228): Uncaught handler: thread AsyncTask #5 exiting due to uncaught exception
01-16 15:27:56.783: E/AndroidRuntime(12228): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-16 15:27:56.783: E/AndroidRuntime(12228):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
01-16 15:27:56.783: E/AndroidRuntime(12228):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
01-16 15:27:56.783: E/AndroidRuntime(12228):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)

Comment: 01-16 15:27:56.783: E/AndroidRuntime(12228):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
01-16 15:27:56.783: E/AndroidRuntime(12228):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
01-16 15:27:56.783: E/AndroidRuntime(12228):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
01-16 15:27:56.783: E/AndroidRuntime(12228):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
01-16 15:27:56.783: E/AndroidRuntime(12228): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: 01-16 15:27:56.783: E/AndroidRuntime(12228):  at com.example.su2.EventMap$GetUsersAsyncTask.doInBackground(EventMap.java:259)
01-16 15:27:56.783: E/AndroidRuntime(12228):  at com.example.su2.EventMap$GetUsersAsyncTask.doInBackground(EventMap.java:1)
01-16 15:27:56.783: E/AndroidRuntime(12228):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
01-16 15:27:56.783: E/AndroidRuntime(12228):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
01-16 15:27:56.783: E/AndroidRuntime(12228):  ... 4 more